# I need help turing a code with 2 loops into a code with one loop, but has the same output

Tags: java, loops

Right now my code is this

```
 import java.text.*; 
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Homework6_EvenOdd
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

  //Varaiable declaration
    int even=50;
    int odd=51;
    //Loop logic for even
    System.out.print("Your even numbers are "+even+", ");
    while (even <= 99)
    {
    even += 2;

    System.out.print(even + ", " );
    } 
    System.out.println ();

    //Loop logic for odd
    System.out.print ("Your odd numbers are "+(odd)+", ");
    while (odd + 1 <= 99)
    {
    odd += 2;

    System.out.print(odd + ", " );
    } 
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this with only one loop.
I don't even know where to start. I can't figure out how I would get the even and odd numbers to print on separate lines if there is only one loop?

Comment: Yet another homework solved by SO ...

Answer (score 3):

Here is variant which produces exact copy of your current output:

```
public class Homework6_EvenOdd {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final StringBuilder even = new StringBuilder();
        final StringBuilder odd = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 50; i <= 100; i++) {
            if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                even.append(i + ", ");
            } else {
                odd.append(i + ", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Your even numbers are " + even.toString());
        System.out.println("Your odd numbers are " + odd.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.text.*; 
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Homework6_EvenOdd
 {
  public static void main(String[] args){
  //Varaiable declaration
    int even=50;
    int odd=51;
    //Loop logic for even
    System.out.print("Your even numbers are "+even+", ");
    while (even <= 99 || odd + 1 <= 99){
    if (even <= 99) {
      even += 2;
      System.out.print(even + ", " );
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (odd + 1 <= 99) {
       odd += 2;
       System.out.print(odd + ", " );
    } 
  }
}
```

Though I have to say this code is not much better. There are much better ways to figure  out if a number is even or odd (hint modulo).

Answer (score 0):

You can collect each of odd and even numbers with List.
After that you can print them.

```
ArrayList<String> odds = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> evens = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 50; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        evens.add(String.valueOf(i));
    } else {
        odds.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}

System.out.println("Your even numbers are: " + String.join(", ", evens));
System.out.println("Your odd numbers are: " + String.join(", ", odds));
```

*Note: [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) is for Java 8 or later.*

Comment: @SaviourSelf Thank you for your suggestion. Ok, I will modify to use `String.join`.